# Comparing cell value to text in Excel VBA: Type mismatch (error 13)

Tags: excel, vba

I have code to convert payroll sheets in a workbook into PDFs, which are then queued up to send to various people within the organization.

Recently, this code started giving

> type mismatch (run-time error 13)

and the debugger referenced this line of code:

```
If sh.Range("Q15").Value Like "?*@?*.?*" Then
```

Full code.

```vb
Sub Mail_Every_Worksheet_With_Address()
'Working only in 2007 and up
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim TempFilePath As String
Dim TempFileName As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim Mailbody As String
    
'Temporary path to save the PDF files
TempFilePath = "C:\Users\Student\Downloads"

'Loop through every worksheet
For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    FileName = ""

    'Test A1 for a mail address
    If sh.Range("Q15").Value Like "?*@?*.?*" Then

        'If there is a mail address in A1 create the file name and the PDF
        TempFileName = TempFilePath & sh.Range("C8").Value & " - " & Format(sh.Range("J8").Value, "yyyy.mm.dd") & ".pdf"
        TempFileName = Replace(TempFileName, ",", _
                      "")

        FileName = Create_PDF(Source:=sh, _
                                  FixedFilePathName:=TempFileName, _
                                  OverwriteIfFileExist:=True, _
                                  OpenPDFAfterPublish:=False)

        'If publishing is OK create the email
        If FileName <> "" Then
        
            With sh
                Mailbody = "<H3><B>" & Range("Q17").Value & "</B></H3>" & _
                  Range("Q18").Value & "<br>" & _
                  Range("Q19").Value & "<br>" & _
                  Range("Q20").Value & "<br>" & _
                  Range("Q21").Value
            End With

            Mail_PDF_Outlook FileNamePDF:=FileName, _
                             StrTo:=sh.Range("Q15").Value, _
                             StrCC:="", _
                             StrBCC:="", _
                             StrSubject:=sh.Range("Q16").Value, _
                             Signature:=True, _
                             Send:=False, _
                             strbody:=Mailbody
        Else
            MsgBox "Not possible to create the PDF, possible reasons:" & vbNewLine & _
                   "Microsoft Add-in is not installed" & vbNewLine & _
                   "You Canceled the GetSaveAsFilename dialog" & vbNewLine & _
                   "The path to Save the file in arg 2 is not correct" & vbNewLine & _
                   "You didn't want to overwrite the existing PDF if it exist"
        End If

    End If
Next sh
End Sub
```

This code was working previously, and was not changed, but today stopped working.

Comment: Not an answer, because there may be a specific answer, but generically this kind of error happens because the cell is empty/missing/null. You may have an invalid worksheet.

Comment: Add an error handller block (i.e Try/Catch) I.e.  `On  Error Resume Next  `.. Code that may raise an error, To catch the error,  `If Err.Number <> 0  DisplayError`   For end of  the Try/Catch block make sure to reset error handling.  i.e.   `On Error GoTo 0  'Stop code and display error ` .   That  way can put a break point  in the Catch error  and  examine what data is causing the error.   i.e. Examine sh.Range("Q15").Value.  Maybe also add  a counter to help identify the location of the cell is causing the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems sh.Range("Q15").Value is not a string.
You may convert it to a string for applying 'Like' operator, like below code.

```
If CStr(sh.Range("Q15").Value) Like "?*@?*.?*" Then
```